# How can I make links white?

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink

How can I change the colour of hyperlinks to white in HTML and CSS?

Comment: Could you consider rephrasing the question to reflect exactly what it is you're after?  For example, "How do I make a link white when a user moves their mouse over?"

Comment: It would be nice for people to assume good faith, this may well be a simple question and perhaps the author's primarly language isn't English. I'm not surprised at the downvotes, but someone actually felt this question offends them? Seriously, that's disappointing.

Comment: I really hope you're not going for white-on-white in order to hide links.  That would be a bad idea.

Comment: @Ross: I'm not sure where the offence came from either, but I can understand the down-votes: the author rolled back several attempts to make the post into a question, which makes it less useful for the community.

Answer (score 29):

Use the [color CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/colors.html#colors).

```
a { color: white; }
```

Problem is, visited links may not be shown as white as well.  You may need to add extra rules:

```
a, a:hover, a:active, a:visited { color: white; }
```

Answer (score 8):

You use CSS

```
a
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Anchor Pseudo-classes:
http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Answer (score 6):

just guessing, you may be looking for these as well:

```
a:link
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

a:visited
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

a:hover 
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Ohh!! then just replace them with #FFFFFF. You will get the white color. However, it was just an example@?!##?@$.

Answer (score 4):

```
a { color: #fff; }
```

in your css file.
I will add that if you're doing it to try and hide many white links on a white background of a page it is a *very bad* idea.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in following ways:

1) If you want to color of hyperlinks to white in HTML specific link, then use

```
<a href="#" style="color:#ffffff;">Some text</a>
```

2) To add color of hyperlinks to white in CSS from entire html page, Create a .css file, In that write following:

```
{ a, a:hover, a:active, a:visited { color: white; }
```

It will suppress color of hyperlinks `white` from every `link`.